# How can I upcase first occurrence of an alphabet in alphanumeric string?

Tags: ruby, string

Is there any easy way to convert strings like `3500goat` to `3500Goat` and `goat350rat` to `Goat350rat`?

I am trying to convert the first occurrence of alphabet in an alphanumeric string to uppercase. I was trying the code below using the method `sub`, but no luck.

```
stringtomigrate = 3500goat

stringtomigrate.sub!(/\D{0,1}/) do |w|
      w.capitalize
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work:

```
string.sub(/[a-zA-Z]/) { |s| s.upcase }
```

or a shorthand:

```
string.sub(/[a-zA-Z]/, &:upcase)
```

examples:

```
'3500goat'.sub(/[a-zA-Z]/, &:upcase)
# => "3500Goat"
'goat350rat'.sub(/[a-zA-Z]/, &:upcase)
# => "Goat350rat"
```

Comment: Thank you @MarekLipka your answer is awesome , can you explain why is this not working for the string "3500goat/about.txt"

Comment: Good reply.. I like it.

Comment: @aravind.udayashankara it does - it capitalizes first occurance of alphabetic character.

Comment: @MarekLipka I could confirm that this solution worked for me thank you for coming forward to help me , Sorry I was wrong some where else while testing . Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
1.9.3-p545 :060 > require 'active_support/core_ext'
 => true 
1.9.3-p545 :099 > "goat350rat to Goat350rat".sub(/[a-zA-Z]/){ |x| x.titleize}
 => "Goat350rat to Goat350rat"
```

Comment: Using `active_support` gem is completely unnecessary here.

Comment: Thanks @anusha for coming forward to help, this too worked for me but I am not in a position to install a new gem . +1 for the effort